# PowerShell: Using PS to get entities (row) from an Azure Table Storage to populate another table

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

Case:
I have 3 tables in Azure Table Storage (Table1, Table2, Table3).

Entities(row) in Table1 are populated after ADO release pipeline runs. Table2 entities (10 rows) are all the rules/Azure policies which are needed to be assigned to every entity that gets populated in Table1, and all the 10 rules for each Table1 entry must be populated into Table3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example of getting rows from one Table and inserting into another in Azure Table Storage. You can change it by including more tables as per your requirements:

Get the context of azure Table Storage:

```
New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "<yourstorageacc>" -StorageAccountKey "<youraccountkey>"
```

Get the reference of first table:

```
$cloudTable = (Get-AzStorageTable –Name "table1" –Context $ctx).CloudTable
```

Get the record that needs to be inserted in another table. Change the filter accordingly:

```
[string]$filter = `
    [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableQuery]::GenerateFilterCondition("username",`
    [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.QueryComparisons]::Equal,"Jessie")
$user = Get-AzTableRow `
    -table $cloudTable `
    -customFilter $filter
```

Get the reference of second table:

```
$cloudTable2 = (Get-AzStorageTable –Name "table2" –Context $ctx).CloudTable
```

Insert the record into second table by using the same $user object that we retrieved.

```
Add-AzTableRow `
    -table $cloudTable2 `
    -partitionKey $partitionKey1 `
    -rowKey ("CA") -property @{"username"=$user.username;"userid"=$user.userid}
```

You can insert/update based on requirement.

Referenced Article: [Perform Azure Table storage operations with Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-how-to-use-powershell)

Comment: Many thanks @AnuragSharma-MSFT. The last part was absolutely the way it worked. However, I had to start by using a "ForEach" to iterate over each entries(10) in Table2. So, It picks the first entry in Table2, assign it to the entry populated to Table1, sends it to Table3, and it repeats for all entries in Table2.